# Does staying in a different EU/EEA country reset the 90/180 Schengen clock?

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I will be staying in Spain for 1 month , another 1 month in Italy and another month in France , and before the 90 days ends , will go to Denmark . My question is when can I come back to EU countries I mentioned  above after a month in Denmark/Switzerland/Germany (or any other continental EEA country)?

I am Canadian and can travel as a non-visa national throughout the EEA.

Comment: Denmark is also part of the EU.

Comment: sorry about that , I mean Switzerland or Germany

Comment: Switzerland and Germany are all part of the Schengen. Please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry about that . what I mean to ask is how long can I stay in Europe as I am from Canada . will retire next year and planning to travel to Spain , Italy & France and may have to stay at least 1 month in each country .

Comment: I have edited your question to include the relevant information and cast a reopen vote on it.  The answer will be the standard Schengen 90/180 rule, but at least the question is no longer unclear :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) consists of 26 Member States, including Denmark, Switzerland and Germany. It doesn't directly overlap with the list of EU countries as some EU members are not part of the Schengen area (UK, Ireland) and some Schengen members are not EU members (Switzerland, Norway).

Traveling between *any* of the Schengen area countries contributes to your 90/180 limit, so you can't reset it by hopping to a different state. However it is possible to travel *outside* the Schengen area (e.g. to UK) and stay there for long enough to reset the Schengen days counter.

For more information on how the 90/180 days rule works, see [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21461/9009) from our related question.